# solve through a loop in java

Tags: java, math, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a `text box(having name b)` and one submit button in `index.jsp`. I will enter something in text box then after clicking `submit` i get that value by in server side `find.jsp`. In find.jsp i get the value by `request.getParameter("b");` In `find.jsp` calaculation is done as shown below:

```
double c=0;
double d=0;

7800.0/12 and 2640.0/12 are fixed.     

if request.getParameter("b")=1 then 

c=7800.0/12*5;// 5 is multiplied with above number(in first one)

d=2640.0/12*5;// 5 is multiplied with above number(in second one) 

if request.getParameter("b")=2 then 

c=7800.0/12*8;// here 5 gets incremented by 3 and became 8(in first one)

d=2640.0/12*8;// same also here( in second one)
```

Similarly if i will enter 20 then accordingly c and d will be calculated. 
I cannot use if-else as any value can be entered in client side and accordingly c and d will be calculated in server side.
How can i implement it in a loop? Many thanks

Comment: Whats the relation between b and 5 ???

Comment: no relation is there. if b=1 then 5 will be multiplied and if b=2 then 5 gets incremented by 3 so 8 will be multiplied like this

Comment: and if b=3?? Whats the equation mutipliedNumber = 5 + f(b) ??

Comment: if b=3 then 8+3=11 will be multiplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    double devide=2.0
    devide = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"))*3+devide

    c=7800.0/(12*devide);
    d=2640.0/(12*devide);
```

Comment: just because u increment 3 at each increment of `b` but 5 in first case  so 2 added by default

Answer (score 1):

You can use for any value to count below one logic.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));
double x=2.0;
double valueForDevide = (value*3)+x;

c=7800.0/(12*valueForDevide );
d=2640.0/(12*valueForDevide );
```